# Limit of the fraction $\dfrac{n(n+1)^\alpha}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm stuck in calculating the following limit:
$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)^\alpha}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha}$$
For what values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ $L$ has a finite value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\alpha>-1$, by [the Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
\begin{eqnarray}
L&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)^\alpha}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^\alpha}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)^\alpha-n(n+1)^\alpha}{(n+1)^\alpha}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)(1+\frac{2\alpha}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))-n(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))}{(1+\frac1n)^\alpha}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1+\alpha+O(\frac{1}{n})}{(1+\frac1n)^\alpha}\\
&=&1+\alpha.
\end{eqnarray}
Here 
$$ (1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+O(x^2). $$
For $\alpha<-1$, let $\beta=-\alpha$. Note that $\beta>1$ and $\{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{\beta}}\}$ converges. Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
L&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)^{-\beta}}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-\beta}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{(n+1)^{\beta}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^{\beta}}}\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}
For $\alpha=-1$, $\{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\}$ diverges and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
L&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n(n+1)^{-1}}{\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-1}}\\
&=&\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}}\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If $\alpha \le -1$, this development is invalid and the result is incorrect.

Comment: @Dr.MV, yes, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.MV, the problem is fixed.

Comment: And a +1.  Well done.  -Mark